# Plane tangent to a sphere - geometric derivation

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, angle, tangent-spaces

Consider a sphere in $\Bbb{R^n}$ centered on $P$. Let $Q$ be a point where some tangent plane meets the sphere. In particular $Q$ is the point on the plane which is the closest to $P$. If $X$ is a point on this tangent plan then $(Q-P)(Q-X) = 0$, and so:
$$(Q-P)X = Q^2-PQ.$$
Now let's isolate $Q^2$ in two different ways:

1. By Pythagoras: $Q^2= P^2-(P-Q)^2$.
2. $(P-Q)^2 = P^2+Q^2-PQ - QP$, so 
   $$Q^2=(P-Q)^2-P^2+PQ+QP.$$

But these two are not the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *"let's get rid of $Q^2$"*? I have no idea what you are doing from this point on.

Comment: Let it be: "Just calculate $Q^2$"
The point is: in a book i'm reading, b) is used. Then $(Q-P)X=(P-Q)^2-P^2+QP$ is a final equation for this tangent plane.
But why $Q^2$ in a) $\neq$ $Q^2$ in b) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythagoras' theorem that tells you that
$$Q^2+(P-Q)^2=P^2,$$
**if $P$ and $Q$ are perpendicular**, which need not be the case here. In general
$$(P+Q)^2=P^2+Q^2+PQ+QP,\tag{1}$$
and in particular, if $P$ and $Q$ are perpendicular this shows that
$$(P+Q)^2=P^2+Q^2.$$
Replacing $Q$ by $-Q$ in equation $(1)$ yields the identity used in the book:
$$(P-Q)^2=P^2+Q^2-PQ-QP,$$
and if $P$ and $Q$ are perpendicular this yields your identity:
$$(P-Q)^2=P^2+Q^2.$$

Comment: Yep, really missed this fact. Indeed. If substitute $Q$'s equation, then it works. Thank you!